# Android Webview Error net::ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE

Tags: android, webview

I am facing an issue in loading a webview. I am trying to load a webPage which requires Cookies and javascript to load the webpage. I am sending cookies and everything but my webview goes to login page instead of opening the page of website.

I am getting error net::ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE inside onReceivedHttpError in my webviewClient.

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH)
       

        webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        webView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        webView.settings.mixedContentMode = 0
        webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        webView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        webView.settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL
        webView.settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS;
        webView.isScrollContainer = false;

        webView.getSettings()
            .setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPD1.170816.004) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Mobile Safari/537.36");



// Clear all the cookies
        webView.clearCache(true)
        webView.clearFormData()
        webView.clearHistory()
        webView.clearSslPreferences()

        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)

        cookieManager.setCookie(
            baseUrl,
            userId
        )

        cookieManager.setCookie(
            baseUrl,
            refreshToken
        )

        cookieManager.setCookie(
            baseUrl,
            loginToken
        )
```

I am setting my javaScript code inside onPageStarted function

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {

                val js =
                    "window.localStorage.setItem('$key', '$value');window.localStorage.setItem('$key1', '$value1');window.localStorage.setItem('$key2', '$username');"
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:$js");
                }
            }

override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                val url: String = request?.url.toString();
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
```

Any Leads will be helpful.

Comment: Have you set the internet permission properly

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa yes, I have added internet permission properly 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />